# Elasticsearch - Sorting by a nested multi-field

Tags: elasticsearch

I've run into a problem while trying to sort on nested multi-field properties in Elasticsearch.  One of the two multi-fields works, the other returns null for every value.

My sortable analyzer:

```
    "analyzer": {
        "sortable": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
    }
```

Mapping:

```
{
    "doc": {
        "properties": {
            "id" : {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "analyzed",
                "analyzer": "snowball",
                "fields": {
                    "sortable": { 
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "sortable"
                    }
                }
            },
            "website": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "domain": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "snowball",
                        "fields": {
                            "sortable": { 
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "sortable"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "created": {
                        "type": "date"
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

A full working example is [here](http://sense.qbox.io/gist/92524e522f5096f98c59cc6f2da7ffa213433536).  Note the four searches at the bottom.  Sorting by name or name.sortable both show values in the sort section of the result.  Sorting by website.domain shows a value in the sort section, but website.domain.sortable always shows null.

I'm hoping I'm just doing something silly here, but for the life of me I can't see what.  This is in Elasticsearch 1.1.0.  I'll gladly also take alternative solutions, though I hate to just slap the field in there twice under two different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require a path for sorting on nested document types.
http://sense.qbox.io/gist/0d05fcf12be64e4a924a6b010ffe55e72d91b147

Comment: Does that really apply though?  I'm adding the "fields" to the string types underneath a nested type, not on the nested type itself.  And the searching does work for both fields.  If I change the search term to "mydomain-com" the snowball-analyzed field (website.domain) matches on "mydomain" or "com", while the sortable field (website.domain.sortable) only matches on the full text "mydomain-com".  New samples at http://sense.qbox.io/gist/cc801f831b45075463ee160146aea279419d0505

And I'll gladly use sense.qbox.io, makes things much easier.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I was doing a exists filter without the nested, so I came with the wrong conclusion. I'm looking into it now. Very strange

Comment: That absolutely worked, not sure how I missed that detail in what I swear was a thorough reading of the documentation.  Many thanks.

Comment: Happens to the best of us, thanks again for using our sense thingy.

Comment: May you update the code? I can not see your gist on qbox. Thanks